# Double-clicking desktop folder opens geany editor instead of clicked folder

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, desktop-shortcuts

When double-clicking a folder icon on the desktop, I expect that folder to be opened in a file browser. On my system, the `geany` editor is opened instead.

Uninstalling `geany` solves the problem. Re-installing `nautilus` and `geany` does not solve the problem.

Environment:

- Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
- Gnome 3.36.8
- geany 1.37.1-2~16.04
- Nautilus (aka files) 3.36.3-stable

Any help resolving this problem will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks. I found more anomalies in my PC, so I just reloaded a saved image. Back to normal

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in your Gnome associates folders with the geany program. Open Nautilus, right click on any folder, properties, "Open With...", "restore default" (or select the file manager you want).